# Cystal Report Accumulated Balance First Record Missing

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

[image]

I have used the following formula in the UnboundNumber (Accumulated balance), but the blue circled field is missing and wrong coming:

```
If Next({SP_Aging;1.AHead}) = Previous ({SP_Aging;1.AHead}) Then 
  numberVar X := (X +  {SP_Aging;1.Balance} )

Else
  X := 0 +{SP_Aging;1.Balance}

;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
// {@Accumulated Balance}

// declare variable; mark as `global` to be explicit (w/o this, the variable is `global`, but this makes it clearer)
Global Numbervar balance;

// if this is the first row, increment the balance; always test for NULL values first in CR
If PreviousIsNull({SP_Aging;1.AHead}) Then

  balance := {SP_Aging;1.Balance}

// if the current row's AHead is the same as previous row's value, increment balance
Else If {SP_Aging;1.AHead} = Previous({SP_Aging;1.AHead}) Then 

  balance := balance + {SP_Aging;1.Balance}

// otherwise, reset
Else

  balance := {SP_Aging;1.Balance}
```